# Extract pattern between a substring and first occurrence of numeric in a string

Tags: sed, matching, substring

Following is the content of a file:

```
xxx_component1-1.0-2-2acd314.xc-linux-x86-64-Release-devel.r
xxx_component2-3.0-1-fg3sdhd.xc-linux-x86-64-Release-devel.r
xxx_component3-1.0-2-3gsjcgd.xc-linux-x86-64-Release-devel.r
xxx_component4-0.0-2-2acd314.xc-linux-x86-64-Release-devel.r
```

I want to extract component names component1 component2 etc.

This is what I tried:

```
for line in `sed -n -e '/^xxx-/p' $file`
do
    comp=`echo $line | sed  -e '/xxx-/,/[0-9]/p'`
    echo "comp - $comp"
done
```

I also tried  `sed -e 's/.*xxx-\(.*\)[^0-9].*/\1/'`

This is based on some info on net. Please give me `sed` command and if possible also explain stepwise

Part 2. I also need to extract  version number from the string.
version number starts with digit and ends with . followed by xc-linux.
As you can see to maintain the uniqueness its has random alphanumeric characters ( length is 7) as part of the version number.

For example :
**xxx_component1-1.0-2-2acd314.xc-linux-x86-64-Release-devel.r**
In this string the version number is :  **1.0-2-2acd314**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to extract the data. The simplest form would be `grep`.

#### GNU `grep`:

You can grab the required data using GNU `grep` with PCRE option `-P`:

```
$ cat file
xxx_component1-1.0-2-2acd314.xc-linux-x86-64-Release-devel.r
xxx_component2-3.0-1-fg3sdhd.xc-linux-x86-64-Release-devel.r
xxx_component3-1.0-2-3gsjcgd.xc-linux-x86-64-Release-devel.r
xxx_component4-0.0-2-2acd314.xc-linux-x86-64-Release-devel.r
```

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=_)[^-]*' file
component1
component2
component3
component4
```

Here we use negative look behind assertion tell to capture everything from `_` to a `-` not incusive.

---

#### `awk`:

```
$ awk -F"[_-]" '{print $2}' file
component1
component2
component3
component4
```

Here we tell `awk` to use `-` and `_` as delimiters and print the second column.

---

#### `sed`:

Having said that, you can also use `sed` to extract required data using group capture:

```
$ sed 's/.*_\([^-]*\)-.*/\1/' file
component1
component2
component3
component4
```

The regex states that match any character zero or more times up to an `_`. From that point onwards, capture everything until a `-` in a group. In the replacement part we just use the data captured in the group by calling it using back reference, that is `\1`.

Comment: Thanks Jaypal. I did little modification in your sed one and it seems to cover all the use cases: This is what I did:   sed 's/xxx_\([^-][^0-9]*\)-.*/\1/' file

Comment: I am here again with another doubt about same pattern. what If i want this part of the pattern **1.0-2-2acd314** ( version no). Going by the above xplaination this should have workd sed `s/*-[0-9].\(^.xc-*\)-.*/\1/'`

Comment: @user3662599 If you can update the question with all possible scenarios, then I can try giving a generic solution that would work for all of them.

Comment: In original question from string `xxx_component1-1.0-2-2acd314.xc-linux-x86-64-Release-devel.r` How do i retrive version number which is **1.0-2-2acd314**  .