# Use Stream Editor (sed) to Obtain Substring within Comma-Delimited Lines

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, delimiter

So I've tried for the large part of today to obtain the username within the following line using sed.

> nesomplefore,Aip1seshoh,female,Ms.,Siri,Rosberg,870 Maxwell Farm Road,Fredericksburg,VA,22408,,540-222-0054,3/24/48,Aries,Cartographer

I have successfully done it using grep because I managed to copy and paste from another post on here, but I haven't had any luck with sed.

Can someone please explain the grep regex and also how to do the same using sed?

```
grep -oP "^([^,]*\,){0}\K[^,]*"
```

I want to be able to pipe the result of the regex in order to add a large number of users dynamically. And please don't refer me to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793965/sed-to-extract-pattern-between-a-substring-and-first-occurance-of-numeric-in-a-s) because I tried following the explanation for sed and the others and don't understand any of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  If we put your sample line into a file named 'test.txt', the following works just fine:

```
sed -e 's/^\([^,]*\),.*/\1/' test.txt
```

Here's what it says:

`s` - search/replace

`/^\([^,,]*\),.*/` - Search from the beginning of the line (`^`) creating a back reference (the escaped parentheses) for any number of characters that are not commas (`[^,]*`).  The `,.*` outside of the closing back reference marker captures the rest of the line.

`/\1/` - Replace the matched strings with the back reference that was stored (the username)

Comment: So from what you wrote I understand that whenever I have two forward slashes I'm creating a "reference" to what's within them that I can then call? Would it be possible to have multiple back references and then say /\1/\2/'? I'm guessing that by the second comma (the one right after the escaped closing parenthesis) you're saying something like "From the beginning of the line match everything that does not contain a comma up to but not including a comma?" Also, and this is really more important to me, why do I need the .* if I don't really care the for the rest of the line? @David Hoelzer

Comment: Not quite.  The forward slashes are delimiting the regular expression.  The parentheses (which are escaped) are creating references.  The first pair lets you use \1, the second \2, etc. so that you can refer to them (refer back.. back references) in the replacement piece.

Comment: The sed command we're using is generally `s/expression/replacement/modifiers`

Comment: So I'm doing

`curl http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~ggome002/cts4348/accounts/users45.csv | tac | tac | head -3 | user=$(sed -n 's/^\([^,]*\),.*/\1/') | useradd $user`

but I'm doing something wrong because nothing seems to happen. Even with the sed p modifier. Sorry for the questions, I'm quite a novice.

Comment: Oh come on, even a novice must wonder why they're doing `tac | tac`. Read a man page, google something or, heaven forbid, pick up a book!

Comment: Actually I know why I'm doing tac | tac | I actually read what it does. Here's what I gathered from it: When doing cURL and pipe to head you will get the error message “curl: (23) Failed writing body (1926 != 13032)”. This just means that head is closing the stream because it’s done with it, but cURL isn’t done reading. So to combat this we can do as this link says [link]http://bit.ly/1KNCctK) and use tac — which is a utility which obtains all of the data passed to it before it hands it off.

Comment: If you don't want `head` to do that and you can't figure out how to stop `head` from doing that (either by `head` or `curl` options), then just don't use `head`, use awk for example: `curl | awk 'NR<4' | ...`

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell us where the "username" appears in your sample input, nor do you show us your expected output, so I don't know which field you want but the tool you want is `cut`, not `sed`:

```
$ echo 'nesomplefore,Aip1seshoh,female' | cut -d, -f1
nesomplefore

$ echo 'nesomplefore,Aip1seshoh,female' | cut -d, -f2
Aip1seshoh
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hw assignment, please pay attention in class as we aren't your tutor. Also don't use specific file names and locations as it poses a security issue...which you would be learning in your class.

Comment: I wouldn't have asked the question if it wouldn't have taken me all day to try to figure out. Not only that, but what is mentioned in class isn't remotely similar to how I am trying to solve the problem. I could easily take the easy way out and write some scripts to do the same but I'd rather learn the commands, their options, and how they interface with one another because, at least to me, it's much more beneficial for growth as opposed to having a multitude of files to accomplish what a series of pipes can do. If you notice, I don't have many questions on here. Thank you for your input.